# Browser extension: recognize browser activity

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, safari

Can I detect system / browser activity from a Safari/Chrome/Firefox/IE extension (plugins or add-ons)? I want to keep a session active in a specific application (like "user active" / "user away") even if the user is away from the tab I'm interested in (imagine a chat application) but doing activities anywhere else (in other tabs or ideally in the system).

I know that javascript security restrictions prevent it from gathering such information outside of the running document (if I stand corrected), so I hope to overcome the limitation with custom extensions. I'm talking about applications running in business intranets, so I can "force" the extension to be installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a plugin work on all url's and you can also bind clicks and what not from a plugin.

Not sure about all browser plugin models but they probably all have a global storage and you can make your chat application check this storage on an interval(and there might just be useful events you can use, but none that I know)

If the browsers` plugin model does not have a global storage, you can probably use an external storage.

This is a pretty generic answer, you probably should just try something :)